# How to run the js code of widget in gridview cell after filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, yii, filter

I'm using Yii 1.x framework.I have a booster TbGridView table,in some cell I added some widget like `select2` and `datetimepicker`  to make it more practical and look better,at the same time I also added a filter at the top of the table.But after used filter,I found the js code that initialize widget not to be used.In HTML code that had generated I found the js code was added at the bottom of page,when I used filter,it's just fresh the table with ajax,so the js code at the bottom was not be used.So,what's the solution at this time.Anybody can help me?please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `afterAjaxUpdate`.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'reinstallDatePicker',
    ...
);

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('re-install-date-picker', "function reinstallDatePicker(id, data) {}");
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/318/using-cjuidatepicker-for-cgridview-filter/

Answer (score 0):

I'm just thinking out loud... since you can listen for ajax requests ([ajaxStart](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/), [ajaxStop](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/)) can you call that widget on ajaxStop.